# rake task return on calling task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I would like to return from a rake task in the calling task.
Does it possible?

Something like in this example, i would like to be able to call task one and one independantly but also one and two sequentially.

```
task: one
   do some work
   if work ok
      task.return true
   else
      puts "task one ko"
      task.return false
   end
end

task: two
   do some work
   if work ok
      task.return true
   else
      puts "task two ko"
      task.return false
   end
end

task: all
  Rake::Task["one"].invoke 
  Rake::Task["two"].invoke
end
```

I am not able to return in the "all" task. And "return" and abort("message") quit the script.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : tasks are lambda blocks that's why we have to use "next" instead "return".